# SwiftUI how to set image for NavigationBar titleView like in UIKit?

Tags: swiftui, swift5, ios-navigationview

I want to set an image in the titleView of NavigationBar in SwiftUI, as we do in UIKit

```
navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))
```

this is how we do it in UIKit.

anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 10):

Here's how to do it:

1. Add [SwiftUIX](https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX) to your project.
2. Set your custom title view via `View.navigationBarTitleView(_:displayMode:)`

Example code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    public var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello World")
                .navigationBarTitleView(MyView())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great, but in order to make the "margins" consistent with the system navigationBar, I needed to chain `.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)` as well.

Comment: Can you please give an Apple reference to `navigationBarTitleView`? I can't find this.

Comment: @ChrisPrince it's a custom modifier in SwiftUIX, it's not part of the official framework :)

Comment: Wow SwiftUIX is a really cool project! Wasn't aware of it but now I'm going to use a ton of it's features
But is it possible using this approach to show a navigationbarTitle with the image?

Answer (score 8):

Simple, Just add your root view into ZStack with top alignment and add your custom center view after root view

```
struct CenterNavigattionBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top){
            //Root view with empty Title
            NavigationView {
                Text("Test Navigation")
                .navigationBarTitle("",displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Text("Cancle"), trailing: Text("Done"))
            }
            //Your Custom Title
            VStack{
                Text("add title and")
                    .font(.headline)
                Text("subtitle here")
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Before Image

[image: 1]

After Image

[image: 2]

Comment: I get a weird space under the navigation bar with this.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a toolbar.
You can add any views

```
  import SwiftUI

  struct HomeView: View {

  // MARK: - Initializer
  init() {
      let appearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
      appearance.isOpaque      = true
      appearance.isTranslucent = false
      appearance.barTintColor  = UIColor(named: "background")
      appearance.shadowImage   = UIImage()
  }


  // MARK: - View
  // MARK: Public
  var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
          VStack(spacing: 20) {
              Text("Hello")
            
              Text("Navigation Bar Test")
          }
          .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
          .navigationBarItems(leading: leadingBarButtonItems, trailing: trailingBarButtonItems)
          .toolbar {
              ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                  VStack {
                      Text("Title").font(.headline)
                      Text("Subtitle").font(.subheadline)
                  }
              }
            
          }
      }
  }

  // MARK: Private
  private var leadingBarButtonItems: some View {
      Button(action: {
        
      }) {
          Text("Left Button")
              .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .medium))
      }
  }

  private var trailingBarButtonItems: some View {
      HStack {
          Button(action: {
            
          }) {
               Text("R1\nButton")
                  .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .medium))
                  .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
          }

          Button(action: {
            
          }) {
              Text("R2\nButton")
                  .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .medium))
                  .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
          }
      }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can't.

There are [two](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview/3340316-navigationbartitle) [overloads](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview/3340317-navigationbartitle) for `.navigationBarTitle()`, taking either a `Text` view or a type conforming to `StringProtocol`. You can't even pass in a modified view like `Text("Title").font(.body)`. This would be a great feature, I'd submit a feature request: http://feedbackassistant.apple.com

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this works for you?

Basically:
Use `GeometryReader` to get the width of the screen
Have `NavigationBarItems(leading: HStack {Spacer() Image("name").resizable().frame(width:..., height: ..., alignment: .center Spacer()}.frame(width:geometry.size.width)`

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .padding()

                    .navigationTitle("test")

                    .navigationBarItems(leading: HStack {
                        Spacer()

                        Image("money")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)

                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```