# Adding Segmented Style Picker to SwiftUI's NavigationView

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationbar, picker, navigationview

The question is as simple as in the title. I am trying to put a `Picker` which has the style of `SegmentedPickerStyle` to `NavigationBar` in `SwiftUI`. It is just like the native `Phone` application's history page. The image is below

[image]

I have looked for Google and Github for example projects, libraries or any tutorials and no luck. I think if nativa apps and WhatsApp for example has it, then it should be possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can put a Picker directly into .navigationBarItems.

[image]

The only trouble I'm having is getting the Picker to be centered. (Just to show that a Picker can indeed be in the Navigation Bar I put together a kind of hacky solution with frame and Geometry Reader. You'll need to find a proper solution to centering.)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var choices = ["All", "Missed"]
    @State private var choice = 0

    @State private var contacts = [("Anna Lisa Moreno", "9:40 AM"), ("Justin Shumaker", "9:35 AM")]

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(self.contacts, id: \.self.0) { (contact, time) in
                        ContactView(name: contact, time: time)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: self.deleteItems)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Recents")
                .navigationBarItems(
                    leading:
                    HStack {
                        Button("Clear") {
                            // do stuff
                        }
                        Picker(selection: self.$choice, label: Text("Pick One")) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< self.choices.count) {
                                Text(self.choices[$0])
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(width: 130)
                        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                            .padding(.leading, (geometry.size.width / 2.0) - 130)
                    },
                trailing: EditButton())
            }
        }
    }

    func deleteItems(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        contacts.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }

}

struct ContactView: View {
    var name: String
    var time: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "phone.fill.arrow.up.right")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                Text("")
            }
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(self.name)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text("iPhone")
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
            Spacer()
            Text(self.time)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Faruk made a good answer for centering the picker: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60510555/8642838

Answer (score 17):

SwiftUI 2 + toolbar:

```swift
struct DemoView: View {

    @State private var mode: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Picker("Color", selection: $mode) {
                        Text("Light").tag(0)
                        Text("Dark").tag(1)
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }
            }
    }
}
```

== update

@iAugus says

> for anyone wants the Picker use its Intrinsic content `size / ideal size`, just apply `.fixedSize()` modifier to it. –

Comment: Perfect! Use .principal for top center, use .bottomBar for something more reachable.

Comment: for anyone wants the `Picker` use its `Intrinsic content size / ideal size`, just apply `.fixedSize()` modifier to it.

Answer (score 6):

For those who want to make it dead center, Just put two `HStack` to each side and made them width fixed and equal.

Add this method to `View` extension.

```
extension View {
    func navigationBarItems<L, C, T>(leading: L, center: C, trailing: T) -> some View where L: View, C: View, T: View {
        self.navigationBarItems(leading:
            HStack{
                HStack {
                    leading
                }
                .frame(width: 60, alignment: .leading)
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    center
                }
                 .frame(width: 300, alignment: .center)
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    //Text("asdasd")
                    trailing
                }
                //.background(Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 100, alignment: .trailing)
            } 
            //.background(Color.yellow)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-32)
        )
    }
}
```

Now you have a `View` `modifier` which has the same usage of `navigationBatItems(:_)`. You can edit the code based on your needs.

Usage example:

```
.navigationBarItems(leading: EmptyView(), center:       
    Picker(selection: self.$choice, label: Text("Pick One")) {
        ForEach(0 ..< self.choices.count) {
             Text(self.choices[$0])
        }
     }
    .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
}, trailing: EmptyView())
```

> UPDATE

There was the issue of `leading` and trailing items were violating `UINavigationBarContentView`'s `safeArea`. While I was searching through, I came across another solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60284658/1404324). It is little helper library called [SwiftUIX](https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX). If you do not want install whole library -like me- I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mrfarukturgut/2e3bb23774bae7649183743268db3e86) just for `navigationBarItems`. Just add the file to your project.

But do not forget this, It was stretching the `Picker` to cover all the free space and forcing `StatusView` to be narrower. So I had to set frames like this;

```
.navigationBarItems(center:
    Picker(...) {
        ...
    }
    .frame(width: 150)
, trailing:
    StatusView()
    .frame(width: 70)
)
```

Comment: That's not going to work, provide an example of a working solution to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you need segmentcontroll to be in center you need to use GeometryReader, below code will provide picker as title, and trailing (right) button.

You set up two view on the sides left and right with the same width, and the middle view will take the rest.
5 is the magic number depends how width you need segment to be.
You can experiment and see the best fit for you.

```
   GeometryReader {
    
    Text("TEST")
     .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                    HStack {
                                        Spacer().frame(width: geometry.size.width / 5)
                                        Spacer()
                                        picker
                                        Spacer()
                                        Button().frame(width: geometry.size.width / 5)
                                           }.frame(width: geometry.size.width)
    
    }
```

But better solution is if you save picker size and then calculate other frame sizes, so picker will be same on ipad & iphone

```
 @State var segmentControllerWidth: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(width: (geometry.size.width / 2) - (segmentControllerWidth / 2))
                    .background(Color.red)
                segmentController
                    .fixedSize()
                    .background(PreferenceViewSetter())
                profileButton
                    .frame(width: (geometry.size.width / 2) - (segmentControllerWidth / 2))
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(PreferenceViewKey.self) { preferences in
                segmentControllerWidth = preferences.width
            }
        }
    
    
    struct PreferenceViewSetter: View {
        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.clear)
                    .preference(key: PreferenceViewKey.self,
                                value: PreferenceViewData(width: geometry.size.width))
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct PreferenceViewData: Equatable {
        let width: CGFloat
    }
    
    struct PreferenceViewKey: PreferenceKey {
        typealias Value = PreferenceViewData
    
        static var defaultValue = PreferenceViewData(width: 0)
    
        static func reduce(value: inout PreferenceViewData, nextValue: () -> PreferenceViewData) {
            value = nextValue()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer how to center segment controller and hide one of the buttons.

```
@State var showLeadingButton = true
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {}, label: {"leading"})
                          .opacity(showLeadingButton ? true : false)


            Spacer()

            Picker(selection: $selectedStatus,
                   label: Text("SEGMENT") {
                segmentValues
                }
             .id(UUID())
             .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
             .fixedSize()

             Spacer()
             Button(action: {}, label: {"trailing"})
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    }
```